# What are the stock amounts for each level?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Does anyone have information on how much stock each level holds and how the amount stocked is impacted by the level's rank and Bitizen skill/dream job?

Comment: Funny!  I asked a similar question and I wound up deleting it because it got no attention or answers.  Thanks for all your hard work!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've created a spreadsheet and shared it on Google Docs:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqutr-RTiVlWdHdOZlg3RFpsc3hKZzE3MkZPRWEwdEE&usp=sharing

The spreadsheet contains the level name, type, rank, # of dream jobs, and total skill. For each stock you enter the Bitizen skill level, and base stock amount. The sheet will then calculate the actual stock level and the time to order. Levels are sorted by their base stock level.

Imperial levels show the completion time and production cost for each item.

Comment: Whenever you are able to do so, don't forget to click that this is the answer to the question.

Comment: Building on what Gobalopper made, here is the complete list:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ambe4WAuPgAUdGVCQ3A5V01HR3N4WHI2STFHR2JzWHc&usp=sharing

It contains the level name, type, rank, skill, base time to complete, modified time to complete (based on total skill of floor), base stock, dream job stock (based on number of dream jobs).

There is another worksheet that lists the imperial levels.

Comment: These lists are useful but neither have been updated to reflect the new Imperial Level info.  Any chance on an update?  I started one of my own but I don't have all of the info since I don't have all of the floors yet.

Comment: Sure, I've updated it with all the new levels. Just missing Imperial Marches but I should have that by Saturday.

Comment: Imperial Marches is:  

Imperial March - 250  
Imperial March Remix - 500  
Imperial March Dubstep - 1500

Comment: THIS is how you succeed in TDS. Just focus on stocking the bigger levels and buy a fast elevator. You'll earn mega bucks (not Bux) in no time.